# Validation of viewstate MAC failed across master pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a home page with a search box and a button on it.

I click the search button and i go to a results page.

the results page also has a search button and when i click it i get the error `Validation of viewstate MAC failed`

```
<% using( Html.BeginForm("Result", "Search" )){ %>
<%= Html.TextBox("SearchText", Model.SearchText)%>
<input value="" type="submit"/>
```

Both pages contain the above piece of code.

If i use the same master page for both pages i don't get the error.  if they use different master pages i get the error.

i have turned off enableEventValidation and viewStateEncryptionMode and i still get the error.

**UPDATE**

When I press the button in both views, the views ActionResult is called, data is collected but when i say return View(myFormViewModel) I get the error.

So all's good as far as the controller is concerned I think.

Comment: Are you using some kind if cookie-less implementation for membership and user state management?. Its sound weird because MVC is not suppose to use ViewState.

Comment: No i'm not using any membership at the moment.  not implemented that at this early stage.

Comment: mmm.. Did you add an MVC View Master Page or traditional Master Page?, i thnk it must be an MVC one, if this is not the problem i really don't know what it can be, specially because it involve a ViwState..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your pages or master pages contain any declarative controls?  Generally these are elements that have a **runat="server"** somewhere in the markup.

You can also see this error if you're using the built-in anti-XSRF helpers.  If you have an action decorated with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken], be sure that any form posting to it contains a call to Html.AntiForgeryToken().

Comment: None of the above.  I don't use runat="server" with my mvc projects.  In fact, the master pages don't contain any controls at all.

Comment: I just tried <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %> coupled with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and no go either.

Comment: Going to give you the answer because in a way you were right.  Should have read my code more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, my fault.

I completely missed the `<form` tag on the second master which meant there was a form within a form on the second master.

So infuriating!

Sorry everyone.